# How do I convert a row from a pandas DataFrame from a Series back to a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating through the rows of a pandas `DataFrame`, expanding each one out into `N` rows with additional info on each one (for simplicity I've made it a random number here):

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
from numpy import random, arange

N=3
x = DataFrame.from_dict({'farm' : ['A','B','A','B'], 
                         'fruit':['apple','apple','pear','pear']})
out = DataFrame()
for i,row in x.iterrows():
    rows = pd.concat([row]*N).reset_index(drop=True)  # requires row to be a DataFrame
    out = out.append(rows.join(DataFrame({'iter': arange(N), 'value': random.uniform(size=N)})))
```

In this loop, `row` is a `Series` object, so the call to `pd.concat` doesn't work.  How do I convert it to a `DataFrame`?  (Eg. the difference between `x.ix[0:0]` and `x.ix[0]`)

Thanks!

Comment: you can do ``s.to_frame()``, but you know this is going to be horribly slow. you are copying the entire frame EACH time you append, not to mention concat copies as well. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Ah. The full problem I'm trying to solve is: my DataFrame `x` has another two columns, `high` and `low`. I want the output `out` to be the same as `x` but with each row replaced with `N` rows, with a new `value` column containing a random number between that row's `high` and `low`. Eg. Farm A might produce between 10 and 20 apples, Farm B between 15 and 25. Then I want 5000 samples of each. I'd love to know a better approach!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you commented, I would try

```
def giveMeSomeRows(group):
    return random.uniform(low=group.low, high=group.high, size=N)

results = x.groupby(['farm', 'fruit']).apply(giveMeSomeRows)
```

This should give you a separate result dataframe. I have assumed that every farm-fruit combination is unique... there might be other ways, if we'd know more about your data.

**Update**

Running code example

```
def giveMeSomeRows(group):
    return random.uniform(low=group.low, high=group.high, size=N)

N = 3
df = pd.DataFrame(arange(0,8).reshape(4,2), columns=['low', 'high'])
df['farm'] = 'a'
df['fruit'] = arange(0,4)
results = df.groupby(['farm', 'fruit']).apply(giveMeSomeRows)
```

df

```
   low  high farm  fruit
0    0     1    a      0
1    2     3    a      1
2    4     5    a      2
3    6     7    a      3
```

results

```
farm  fruit
a     0        [0.176124290969, 0.459726835079, 0.999564934689]
      1           [2.42920143009, 2.37484506501, 2.41474002256]
      2           [4.78918572452, 4.25916442343, 4.77440617104]
      3           [6.53831891152, 6.23242754976, 6.75141668088]
```

If instead you want a dataframe, you can update the function to

```
def giveMeSomeRows(group):
    return pandas.DataFrame(random.uniform(low=group.low, high=group.high, size=N))
```

results

```
                     0
farm fruit            
a    0     0  0.281088
           1  0.020348
           2  0.986269
     1     0  2.642676
           1  2.194996
           2  2.650600
     2     0  4.545718
           1  4.486054
           2  4.027336
     3     0  6.550892
           1  6.363941
           2  6.702316
```

Comment: And finally, if the column name `=0` in the last example bothers you, add `columns=['values']` to the `DataFrame()` command :)

Comment: This is much neater than my approach. Thank you!

Comment: What's the best way to give the level_3 index (0,1,2,0,1,2,...) a name, eg. 'iter'?